# How to Add timestamp with digital signature while signing a text file?

Tags: java, timestamp, digital-signature

I have a text file to which I have to apply digital signature. I am able to sign and verify the content of text file. I followed [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html) for signing and verification.

I want to add timestamp information to signature, how can I do that ?

Comment: The code you use generates a fairly naked signature. To bundle signature and timestamp information, you should look into creating signature containers (PKCS#7 / CMS) which enrich the naked signatures in many ways.

Comment: @mkl can you please share some link to source to implement that ?

Comment: I'd propose using BouncyCastle. You might want to start with code [like this](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html).

Comment: @mkl Thanks a lot :) Well I am using a usb token for signing, Tokne is provided by some CA, I will try it.